# What is wrong with this email RegExp?

Tags: regex, jquery-validate

I'm trying to implement [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) (the one at the bottom of the page) RegExp to validate email addresses with jquery validation plugin.

This is my code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("email_address", function(value, element, param) {
  var email_regexp = new RegExp("[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+)*@(?:a-z0-9?.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b", "g");
  var result = value.match(email_regexp);
  return result ? result.length >= param : false;
}, "Invalid email address");
```

No JS errors are shown, still it doesn't validate anything! Been playing with it for like an hour and can't get this working!

Is there something wrong?

**EDIT:** I tried also with `//` delimiters:

```
$.validator.addMethod("email_address", function(value, element, param) {
  var result = value.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_{|}~-]+)*@(?:a-z0-9?.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b/g);
  return result ? result.length >= param : false;
}, "Invalid email address");
```

Comment: What's wrong with this email regex? It's an email regex. That's what's wrong. I suggest you stop "playing" and begin some methodical debugging! Come back when you have steps and results to show us. An hour isn't a very long period of time to be working on a problem.

Comment: [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Your Complex Regex](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Comment: Yup. Email address are too complex for regular expressions. While they are a regular language, it's just too much for one expression.

Comment: Yeah, too complex for me too, but my employer found that webpage and want me to implement **THAT** regex :)

Comment: I started typing a list of all the errors, but I came to the conclusion that it is just completely wrong. Tell your employer (politely) that regular expressions should not be used for email addresses. Sorry. But it's the truth.

Comment: **Why are you writing a custom rule for something already built into the plugin?**  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/email

Comment: @TylerCrompton, so what's the alternative then?  Using regex is how the `email` method already works within the jQuery Validate plugin.

Comment: @Sparky, that depends on what you are using these email addresses for. It's it's strictly to store information, then you should write a parser or borrow one that's already been done (no need to reinvent the wheel). If you are sending emails to these email addresses, why not just try sending an email to them and have them confirm? That way, you get away with `\.+@.+` as your regex (with the DOTALL flag or its equivalent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why are you writing a custom regex function for the jQuery Validate plugin when it already has an `email` rule built-in?**

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/email

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            field: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form id="myform">  
     <input type="text" name="field" />  <br/>  
     <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Working Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/sRwHc/

---

**The default regex function used within the `.validate()` plugin, FYI:**

```
email: function(value, element) {
    // contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
    return this.optional(element) || /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/i.test(value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$
//     ^^
```

That `\.` will need escaping again for the Javascript string:

```
~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$
//     ^^^
```

Or, preferably, use `//` delimeters rather than constructing a `RegExp` object from a string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Still not validates. Also tried with // delimiters. I'll update the question adding the new code I tried

Comment: @jviotti: This is why we need you to go away and perform methodical debugging. Test individual parts of the regex. We're just not going to keep coming back and updating our answers 20 times for every step of debugging we do together. This whole thing would be best done in a chatroom or something I think